# iOS11 photo library access is possible even if settings are set to "never"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: { })
}
```

Even if I set access to Photos in Settings to "Never" with above code I can still present image picker and show photos. I'll check for `PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()` before showing it, but I would like to know is this expected behaviour?

Comment: which key have you add in info.plist?

Comment: Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

Comment: Did you try with simulator or device ?

Comment: I'm testing on device

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks, but question is why I'm still allowed to present picker if my settings say access to photos: "never"

Comment: Is device jailbroken ?

Comment: @TofaaniKaanudo no

Comment: @gvuksic I noticed in my device too. Even though I have set the permission to **Never**, it is still allowing me to choose photos.

Comment: Crazy with this issue, I checked in simulator even it will not be ask permission to access photo library.

Comment: iOS 11 => Also facing access permission https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405881/ios-11-not-asking-permission-for-access-photo-from-the-app

Comment: @gvuksic Any luck on this issue?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Okay, you can sort of piece this together from answers and comments already, but to try to tell a more complete story...

---

In iOS 11, `UIImagePickerController` runs as a separate process from your app. That means:

1. Your app can't see the user's whole Photos library — it gets read-only access just for whichever asset(s) the user chooses in the image picker.
2. Because of (1), your app doesn't need the standard privacy authorization for Photos library access. The user explicitly chooses a specific asset (or multiple) for use in your app, which means the user is granting your app permission to read the asset(s) in question.

You can see more about this [in the WWDC17 talk on PhotoKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017-505/?time=141).

(By the way, this model matches what you've seen [in the Contacts framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contactsui/cncontactpickerviewcontroller) since iOS 9; if you show contact picker, your app only gets a one-time drop of contact information for the contact(s) the user picked, not ongoing read/write access to the Contacts database, so the contact picker doesn't require special privacy permission.)

---

`PHPhotoLibrary` and its authorization status reflect the global read/write permission for Photos access that users can control from Settings > Privacy. (That's the one where your Info.plist needs `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`.) Any use of the `PHPhotoLibrary` API requires this permission, regardless of whether your app's use of that API is only for writing or only for reading. This has been true since PhotoKit was introduced in iOS 8.

If you're not using `PHPhotoLibrary`, `PHAsset`, etc, there are narrower permission options that are new in iOS 11 (and not part of the Photos.framework API):

- As noted above, `UIImagePickerController` doesn't need blanket Privacy Settings permission because each use grants one-time read access for the specific assets chosen.
- If you need only to add new assets to the Photos library, use [`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum) or [`UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1619162-uisavevideoatpathtosavedphotosal). With those you can put `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` in your Info.plist — then the system's Privacy Settings will make clear to the user that they're not giving your permission to see or modify existing assets, only to add new ones.

  If the user grants add-only permission, it applies only to those UIKit functions — attempting to use `PHPhotoLibrary` will still prompt for (and require the Info.plist key for) read/write access.

  See [this part of the WWDC17 talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017-505/?time=505) for more on the add-only privacy setting.

Comment: I was following the "Start developing iOS Apps" tutorial using iOS 11 and didn't get an error when the tutorial said I should've gotten one. This answer explains why that's the case :D

Answer (score 6):

**Is this expected behaviour?** - YES.

From the docs - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619144-issourcetypeavailable

> true if the device supports the specified source type; false if the specified source type is not available.

It tells you if the device supports the source type and not if the app has the permission to access it.

As you already mentioned in the question, `PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()` would be correct way to check this.

Answer (score 6):

This (new) behaviour **does** sound logical to me, here's why. When using `UIImagePickerController` your app doesn't actually get access to *any* photos. It only sees the one your user has picked, when that happens; and if the user taps Cancel in the picker none of those become available to the app.

`PHPhotoLibrary` is part of a separate framework, [Photos](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos), where you can do a lot of stuff with the user's photo library, and therefore need permission.

So if you are only using `UIImagePickerController` I'd suggest **not** mixing Photos stuff in.

Disclaimer: haven't heard of any official statement from Apple folks. [This forum thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86974) looks relevant, maybe we get a reply there. **UPD:** [there it is](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86974#271938), same idea.

Also, if you're evil enough you can theoretically fiddle with `UIImagePickerController` view hierarchy at runtime and examine whatever the user sees there. But that's again for Apple to deal with, we should just be nice :-)

Answer (score 3):

UIImagePickerController and PHPhotoLibrary responsible for different areas.

You should check both: auth status and source availability.

**PHAuthorizationStatus**

> Information about your app’s **authorization to access** the user’s Photos
>   library.

**isSourceTypeAvailable**

> **Discussion**
>
> Because a media source may not be present or may be **unavailable**,
>   devices may not always support all source types.
>
> **For example**, if you
>   attempt to pick an image from the user’s library and the library is
>   empty, this method returns false. Similarly, if the camera is already
>   in use, this method returns false.