# iOS 11 not asking permission for access photo from the app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios11

As title saying, generally App that use photo library or camera it will be first time asked your permission to access.

For my App till iOS 10.x asking permission but run app with iPhone 8+ and iOS 11 then **not asking permission** even **not display** my App in setting ?

If anybody know then please help me to improve my knowledge.

Note: I set all the required key in `info.plist` file.

> 1) NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription // for iOS 11
>   2) NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
>   3) NSCameraUsageDescription

Comment: Can you show some codes? Are you using `UIImagePickerController`?

Comment: It's just simple code that we used as usual for capturing photo or get from library.

Comment: iOS 11 doesn't need permission to show `UIImagePickerController` because it runs out-of-process now; see answers to the duplicate question for details.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Have you find any solution? @Tofaani Kaanudo

Comment: @pigeon_39 - No dear

Comment: Okay it is a duplicate question, @rickster please direct us to the original question so we can get answered

Comment: Depending on how you’re viewing SO, there’s a banner somewhere showing this question is closed as a duplicate *with a link to the original question*. But if you can’t find that, here’s an extra link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46404628/957768