# UIImagePickerController receiving access without asking

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm showing a `UIImagePickerController`, and it does not ask for permissions, but it has access to all photos and albums. I tried reinstalling the app, using a different bundle identifier (on device, as well) and resetting the simulator.

The app doesn't even appear in Settings > Privacy > Photos and doesn't have this entry in Settings > MyApp, either. I do have `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` in my `Info.plist`. I don't need the camera.

```
let controller = UIImagePickerController()
controller.sourceType = sourceType
controller.delegate = self
controller.allowsEditing = true

currentViewController.present(controller)
```

Printing `PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()` outputs `0`, which is `.notDetermined`, as expected.

Other answers I've found include trying what I've already tried.

Thank you!

Comment: try different device

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46594741/3747037 related to iOS 11

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alok!