# UIImagePickerController and info.plist issue

Tags: ios, swift

In my project I tried to add two things:

1. A camera source for a person's avatar.
2. add permission for the camera and photo library access in the ***info.plist*** file.

But when I tried to test my app in a real device the app doesn’t show any permission, and when I chose the camera the app exit without error message in the log console?

For the info.plist I use this two line:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use</string>
```

And add a photo I use this code:

```
@objc func addNewPerson(){
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Choose image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let camera = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default){
        [weak self] _ in
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            picker.allowsEditing = false
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.sourceType = .camera
            self?.present(picker,animated: true)
        }else{
            let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    ac.addAction(camera)

    let galerie = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo library", style: .default){
        [weak self] _ in
            picker.allowsEditing = true
            picker.delegate = self
        self?.present(picker,animated: true)
    }
    ac.addAction(galerie)

    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))

    present(ac,animated: true)   
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: before you show that UIAlert you should test if the user already granted access to his camera .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `addNewPerson()` method before showing the alert you should check if the user already granted access to his Camera you can do that by :

```
if AVCaptureDevice.AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(AVMediaTypeVideo) ==  AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized {
    // Already Authorized
} else {
    AVCaptureDevice. requestAccess(AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: { (granted: Bool) -> Void in
       if granted == true {
           // User granted
       } else {
           // User rejected
       }
   })
}
```

and before that make sure you added [image]

Comment: Thank you very much bro.
There is some note, I want to add to your response:
1. _**AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType**_ has been changed to _**AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus**_ 
2.  _**AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType**_ has been changed to _**AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess**_

Comment: thanks Bro , I will update the answer for future people who got the same issue .

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention, in iOS 11 camera access is not required to use the UIImagePicker

Here is copy-pasted fragment from [rickster's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404628/ios11-photo-library-access-is-possible-even-if-settings-are-set-to-never/46594741#46594741).

> in iOS 11, UIImagePickerController runs as a separate process from your app. That means:
>
> Your app can't see the user's whole Photos library — it gets read-only access just for whichever asset(s) the user chooses in the image picker.
> Because of (1), your app doesn't need the standard privacy authorization for Photos library access. The user explicitly chooses a
> specific asset (or multiple) for use in your app, which means the user is granting your app permission to read the asset(s) in question.